# How to find fit of points to line that is not line of best fit?

Tags: r, regression

I'm attempting to find how well my points fit into a line that is not the line of best fit, but a line that I have determined myself.

Is it possible to fit a R-squared and p-value in R studio to see how well my data points fit a manually input line?

Comment: Its possible ... just use the formula for r2 from any statistics textbook. You will have to decide for your self how many x and y values to use for your formula (I imagine 10 to 15 would be good). P values can probably be resolved similarly - just check the method for conducting a p-test with linear regression and repeat those steps (offhand, I'm not sure what criteria is used or how it is done with linear regression - but I think I have seen such kinds of p-values so I guess there is a way to do it).

Comment: I don't know what hypothesis your p-value would check. You can certainly calculate an R^2 value. You could probably do a likelihood ratio test compared to a line of best fit. If this is a purely theoretical question, you should ask at stats.stackexchange. If this is a programming question, you should provide some sample data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding *R*² given a set of points, line slope, and intercept is relatively straightforward:

```
r2_line <- function(x_obs, y_obs, m, b) {
  y_pred <- m * x_obs + b
  ssr <- sum((y_obs - y_pred)^2)
  sst <- sum((y_obs - mean(y_obs))^2)
  1 - (ssr / sst)
}

# example data: f(x) = 2x + 4 + normally-distributed error
set.seed(13)
x <- runif(20, -10, 10)
y <- 2 * x + 4 + rnorm(20, sd = 5)

# test fit of f(x) = 2x + 4
r2_line(x, y, m = 2, b = 4)
# 0.8409438

# test fit of f(x) = 1.5x + 5
r2_line(x, y, m = 1.5, b = 5)
# 0.7610168
```

As @GregorThomas points out, *p* value is less straightforward.